# How do I store environment variables both locally and not to have to change code when deploying on Heroku in Django

Tags: django, heroku, environment-variables, boto

I have a Django project I have been working on offline and now I have hosted it on Heroku and it works well on Heroku but fails on my local machine with this error.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DEBUG'
```

and I think it is because I used environment variables like this.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
import os

DEBUG = S3Connection(os.environ['DEBUG'], os.environ['DEBUG'])
```

I also have a `.env` file in my root(project folder) with the environment variables like this.

```
export JWT_SECRET_KEY = "dfge..."
export DEBUG = 1
```

What is the right way to store the environment variables on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

I have local file `secret.py` added to `.gitignore` with all keys, env values needed:

```
#secret.py
DEBUG = 1
```

Then in `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py
try:
    import secret
    DEBUG = secret.DEBUG
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    DEBUG = S3Connection(os.environ['DEBUG'], os.environ['DEBUG'])
```